# How to create columns with defined width -R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create an empty table / matrix which will be filled with values later on.
data columns (example below for "Prec01 (p)" and "Prec04 (p)") should have a fix width of 11 signs (will be a program specific ascii format)

```
!!Date           Prec01 (p) Prec04 (p)
1992 10 02 00:00        0.4        0.0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `formatC`, for example :

```
paste0("Prec", formatC(1:10, width = 3, flag = 0 ), "(p)")
```

`flag` is used to fill the empty character with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks!
I did it like this: create an empty vector (unfortunately this is a character vector, hope it works, but I dond't know how to specify it the other way)

```
col <- vector(length=length(dwd[,2]))
for(i in 1:length(dwd[,2])){
col1[i]<- paste(formatC(x=dwd[i,2],width = 11, flag =  ))
}
```

it does the job.
Best regards
Jochen

Comment: In your answer, `flag = ` isn't doing anything, just leave it off, it looks weird as-is (if you want specify the default of a space, set `flag = " "`, but this is the default so it's unnecessary). Also, you don't need to wrap `formatC` in `paste()` unless you're actually pasting something to it. And, as @Mamoun's answer shows, `formatC` is vectorized so the for loop is unnecessary. So, just do `col1 = formatC(x = dwd[, 2], width = 11)`.